# Creating xls in javascript using ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, activex, activexobject

My code

```
    var fsobj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var excelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

    var wbobj = excelApp.Workbooks.Add;
    var wsobj = wbobj.Worksheets(1);
```

When I use the below code it works fine (i.e., it executes excel and fills in two rows)

```
    wsobj.Cells(1,1).value="Hello";
    wsobj.Cells(2,1).value=compareData.response.length;
    wbobj.Application.visible=true;
```

But when I use this below code it says `Expected ';'` in 3rd line (with Hello), I am not able to find what is the problem here. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jnGr6/1/) is the jsfiddle link, not working though, if anyone can make it work

```
    for(i=0;i<compareData.response.length;i++)
    {
        wsobj.Cells(i,1).value="Hello";
    }
    wbobj.Application.visible=true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row numbers in Excel start from 1, not from 0. You should write

```
for(i=0; i<compareData.response.length; i++)
{
    wsobj.Cells(i + 1, 1).value="Hello";
}
```